# Linux files ownership and permissions

Tags: linux, file, filesystems

I have Linux VPS and few accounts there. I used SSH with root logins to copy files from one account to another (e.g. in this folder
/home/firstacc/public_html/forum I typed cp -R * /home/secondacc/public_html/community). 
Now when I use regular FTP to edit files on secondacc - I can't modify it - SmartFTP says permission denied. Now how do change ownership or permissions so they can be edited via regular FTP ?

Comment: for questions not related to programming, [so] might be the wrong place. try [sf] or [su] for problems with administration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `chmod` to set the permissions (but be careful not to allow any wild process to modify your files) and `chown`/`chgrp` to change ownership/group-membership of your file.

ideally you would create a group (i call it 'fancyhomepage') where both users are members thereof:

```
# addgroup fancyhomepage
# adduser firstacc fancyhomepage
# adduser secondacc fancyhomepage
```

then make sure that all files you want to share belong to this group and are group-writeable

```
$ chgrp -R fancyhomepage /home/secondacc/public_html/community/
$ chmod -R g+rwX /home/secondacc/public_html/community/
```

Answer (score 0):

`$ chown -R <user>:<org>` on the directory changes the permissions for everything in the directory and below.